# It's possible to use React to read a html table rendered by React components?

Tags: reactjs, export, rendering, export-to-excel, data-export

We already have a system which generated and render some data based on queries. For the users, the result is an HTML table that can be seen on the web.
Now we need to export that data, but due to the component structure, there is no possibility to create a variable to push the data and to be exported it as an xls or csv format. Or are least we had been struggling that way and there is no result.

Some of you know if there could be possible a function or a way to read the HTML data renderized to be exported on csv or xls format?

That's part of the code for the render. We are using queries to take the data an assign it to different components.

```
 <div className="d-flex h-auto flex-column">
                <Button type="primary" className="my-5 align-self-right" onClick={() => this.groupSum(allCodes, allCodesInit, allNits, allNitsInit, allCreditos, allDebitos, sumsInit)}>Generar</Button>
                <div className="table-responsive" id="table-report">
                    <table className="table table-active mb-0">
                        <thead className="thead-light">
                            <tr>
                                {/* <td colSpan="2"></td> */}
                                <td colSpan="5" style={widthStyle} className="text-center">
                                    <h1 className="text-uppercase d-block mb-0">{client}</h1>
                                    <h5>NIT {nit}</h5>
                                </td>
                                {/* <td colSpan="2"></td> */}
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><small><b>Reporte:</b></small></td>
                                <td className="no-top"><small>Balance de prueba</small></td>
                                <td style={widthStyle}></td>
                                <td><small><b>Fecha:</b></small></td>
                                <td className="no-top"><small>{new moment().format('L')}</small></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><small><b>Rango:</b></small></td>
                                <td><small>{monthInitial} - {monthFinal}</small></td>
                                <td style={widthStyle}></td>
                                <td><small><b>Página:</b></small></td>
                                <td><small>1/1</small></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colSpan="5" style={fullWidthStyle}></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    <table className="table table-active">

                        <thead className="thead-light">
                            <tr className="text-center">
                                <th scope="col">Código</th>
                                <th scope="col" colSpan="1">Nombre</th>
                                <th scope="col">Saldo anterior</th>
                                <th scope="col">Débitos</th>
                                <th scope="col">Créditos</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nuevo saldo</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <FirstLvlCodes
                                deep={deep.toString()}
                                reportType={this.props.reportType}
                                thirdNits={[...this.props.thirdNits, ...this.props.suppliers].sort((a, b) => a.nit-b.nit)}
                                codes={this.state.codes}
                                codesInit={this.state.codesInit}
                                allCodes={this.state.allCodes}
                                allCodesInit={this.state.allCodesInit}
                                codesTree={this.state.codesTree}
                                nits={this.state.nits}
                                nitsInit={this.state.nitsInit}
                                firstLvlCodes={this.state.firstLvlCodes}
                                secondLvlCodes={this.state.secondLvlCodes}
                                thirdLvlCodes={this.state.thirdLvlCodes}
                                fourthLvlCodes={this.state.fourthLvlCodes}
                                fifthLvlCodes={this.state.fifthLvlCodes}
                                sixthLvlCodes={this.state.sixthLvlCodes}
                                debitos={this.state.debitos}
                                creditos={this.state.creditos}
                                sumsInit={this.state.sumsInit}
                            />
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

We appreciate your help!
Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you truly cannot access the data that you're passing to the React component, if you can give it an ID you can read the `td`s from the dom, e.g. `[...document.getElementById('table').querySelectorAll('tr')].map(tr => [...tr.querySelectorAll('td')].map(td => td.innerText).join(';')).join('\n')`

Comment: Thanks for your help @cbr!
We are using many components to create the table, I had tried your solution, assigning the code to a variable, and assigning an ID to the table, but it results in an error, which says: **codeUnhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null**